# Make 2 different application MSI to work as major upgrade with each other

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, installshield

There are 2 different product MSI. Both the MSI have **different Product Code and Upgrade Code.**
When 1 MSI is installed, I need the second MSI to install as a Major upgrade .
So I made the **upgrade code of both the MSI same** . Also In the "Upgrades" View in Installshield I have added the check to detect the same upgrade code . But it is not working . The log says "No related product found".  Is it possible to make 2 different product MSI to work as major upgrade ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two different product's MSIs then keep ProductCode and UpgradeCode different. This should be standard practice.

In order for 2nd MSI to upgrade from 1st MSI, change the major upgrade setting to **"Products having another upgrade Code"** in 2nd one and add the UpgradeCode of 1st MSI here. This should be enough to cater your scenario.

[image]

Comment: The above solution works perfectly fine for the requirement ! @Vivek Jaiswal